# JQVMap onload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

I'm using JQVMap to render a world map on a webpage. According to the documentation, the map API includes events for onLabelShow, onRegionOver, onRegionOut, and onRegionClick, like so:

```
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        onLabelShow : function (event, label, code){},
        onRegionOver : function (element, code, region){},
        onRegionOut : function (element, code, region){},
        onRegionClick: function(element, code, region){},
    });
```

Is there a way to target an onload event to run some code when the map first renders? I have a function I need to run when the map loads, but it requires the 'region' response that's available within the included API events. I tried just running my function after the map code like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_en',
        onLabelShow : function (event, label, code){},
        onRegionOver : function (element, code, region){},
        onRegionOut : function (element, code, region){},
        onRegionClick: function(element, code, region){},
    });

    location.hash = region; //code I need to run after map loads
});
```

But the console doesn't recognize 'region' outside of the vectorMap({}); function. I've also tried this:

```
    jQuery('#vmap').ready( function(event, code, region) {
            location.hash = region; //code I need to run after map loads
    });
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: It's not clear what's your goal... You need the hash when the page/map loads or when the user clicks something? What's the action flow? Because if we add `location.hash=region;` inside `onRegionClick()` it works ok. . . . ps: you may like [this code to generate a printable image](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/xbe5ke6q/3/) of jQvmap . . . . . ps2: a [StackFiddle set up with jQVmap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25843258/1287812)

Comment: did you check the scope of location.hash?